# Difference between empty value ENUMs

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

The value of review_type for all my stuff is empty (not null though)

review_type is defined like this `ENUM('','a','m','f')`

All 1108 records look like this

[image]

But 1000 records don't come back when I search for records with empty review_type. And when I search for records with not empty review type, I get 0. What's up with those 1000 records? How is this possible?

```
SELECT id, review_type FROM stuff; -- 1108 records
SELECT id, review_type FROM stuff WHERE review_type=''; -- 108 records
SELECT id, review_type FROM stuff WHERE review_type!=''; -- 0 records
-- column type is defined as NOT NULL, but just to be sure:
SELECT id, review_type FROM stuff WHERE review_type IS NULL; -- 0 records
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL enums empty value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174593/mysql-enums-empty-value)

Comment: Have you tried running a distinct query on review_type. Could you please post the output of the same ?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan there are 2 records, both with empty values that look the same (0 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

The 1000 missing records have a value of `0`

If you set ENUM value to 0, it gets an empty value that's different from the empty value I defined `ENUM('','a','m','f')` which has a value of `1`.

There's 2 different empty values. `''` refers to mine, and `0` lets me get the other one