# How to restrict the default empty string while inserting a row into a table using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a row into a table using sqlalchemy in my python flask application. But if I didn't gave any values to a column then it's automatically inserting empty string. I need to restrict it. If there's no/irrelevant value I need to fail the insertion.

Let say I'm having a table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE person(
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
    age int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Age',
    sex ENUM('M','F') NOT NULL COMMENT 'sex',
    CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON PRIMARY KEY  (id ASC) 
)
```

`data = {'name': 'xyz', 'sex': 'Z'}`
I'm trying to insert a row using a json object without some values/irrelevant values. At that time it needs to throw some exception but automatically it is taking empty string.

I searched almost everywhere, I can't able to find a solution for this. In table model also i defined like this,

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    sex = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

But I don't know how it's automatically taking empty strings.

I'm inserting data like this,

```
stmt = Person.__table__.insert().values(data)
       db.session.execute(stmt)
       db.session.commit()
```

Expected response:
I'm expecting some exceptions for sex column like non acceptable values and for age I didn't gave any value for a not null column, So expecting a exception for that also.

Actual response:
It's inserting without any exception using empty strings

```
id | name | age | sex
1    xyz
```

*For age and sex the values are empty strings

Help me to resolve this.

Comment: `stmt = db.session.query(Person).insert().values(data)` raises `AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'insert'`

Comment: Change this: `stmt = db.session.query(Person).insert().values(data)` to this: `stmt = db.insert(Person).values(data)`. Then change `session.execute(stmt)` and `session.commit()` to `db.session.execute(stmt)` and `db.session.commit()` (I assume the incorrect indentation in your example is a copy-paste error). On mysql I get `sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'sex' at row 1`.

Comment: Let's consider that Person as a table object. like `Person.__table__.insert().values(data)`. YEah, Sorry that indentation is a copy paste error only. Will update it. Thanks

Comment: Still it's inserting empty string If there's some wrong values(for ENUM column) or no values for other columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174705/6560549

Comment: Hooo, Sorry bro. I forgot this sql_mode. 
`set global sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';` This resolves this issue. But I need to check which one is best way. Anyway thanks for your reference.